# Bash reverse-search malfunctioning sometimes

Tags: bash

When using the reverse-search feature in bash (Strg+R), typing some letters and pressing TAB, We encounter an error like in following example

```
(reverse-i-search)`sudo servi': ^Cdo service omd-0.54 restart
```

ends up in:

```
  user@server:~$ -bash: words: bad array subscript
   -bash: words: bad array subscript
   -bash: words: bad array subscript
   -bash: words: bad array subscript
```

We have `GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) on Debian Squeeze` and bash-completion package from standard repository installed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that its a normal "known" problem due to the fact that bash-completion reacts on "Tab". Reverse-i-search is normally used with again pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to search through all results and the right arrow to use the command.